# Is it possible to show the AddThis buttons only after the GDPR box was clicked and hidden using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, addthis

I have a bar that appears at the bottom which allows my users to accept cookies (as per GDPR).

Only the AddThis buttons appear there too whenever I run on a cell phone (on a Desktop it's not a problem since the buttons appear on the right side instead.)

The GDPR is becoming even more important and thus I'd like to give that priority over AddThis. Have that visible until clicked and once clicked let people share my pages with AddThis that appears then.

Right now, AddThis appears on top of the GDPR bar rendering the bar useless.

What I'd like to do is get the AddThis buttons only after the GDPR bar was dismissed. Is there an easy way to do that? Would it be by adding the AddThis script dynamically once the GDPR bar was removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

The GDPR says, that no marketing cookie shall be set - only cookies required due technical reasons (e.g. session, language, currency).
You will be safe to disable all other cookies as long as the visitor has not explicit agreed to them.
Furthermore you should give visitors the option to select which cookies they allow.

Under marketing cookies fall all like those from Google (Analytics etc.) - regardless if IP anonymization is enabled inside the code - and especially those from AddThis (the more as they are bought by Oracle).

It seems that you have to develop a module/plugin/extension to your system which gives the visitors the right choice.
If then he has agreed, you can set the cookie.

**Only hiding the code is not enough (have seen already some useless tips to do so by CSS).**

Comment: @Alexis Wilke Thx for grammar, wrote too fast and did not read again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add AddThis script via a tag management tool (like Google tag manager), so you can hold the script until you get the consent from the visitor.